# Creating a table - the easiest way possible

Tags: tables

I'm working on a website and I need the users to define the columns for a table. 
There are different types of columns which might be text, numeric, URL, email and so on. So every column has the name and the type. 
This is a critical step in the service and I need this process to be as easy as possible. Tests showed that our current method, which is text input and a drop down for each column is not intuitively translated in users' understanding to column title and type...
I'm looking for solutions, including to buy a component that can let the users do it in the easiest way possible. 
Thanks for your help guys!!

Comment: Reads like a homework assignment, but even so, a good approach is to ask your users what they expect, then do some experiments to see what works best for them. Good luck.

Comment: Already done, the current approach is not working well. I'm looking for a way to create a table using drag and drop or possibly some other solution.

Comment: Okay, so what did they say when you asked them? In my experience, it is rare for users to have no clue about what they want.

Comment: _"Tests showed that our current method, which is text input and a drop down for each column is not intuitively translated in users' understanding to column title and type"_ Why not? Not trying to be smart, but on the face of it using text input and drop down is a totally reasonable and appropriate solution, so it makes me think the implementation is the problem, not the choice of controls. Can you share a screenshot etc to help us better appreciate what's going on?

Comment: Have you indicated to your users beforehand, that you're building a table for them, and each set of text and dropdown translate into a table column?

Answer (score 2):

If you treat this like a conversation, it would probably go something like this:

- Human "I want a new column in my table"
- System "What do you want to call your new column?"
- Human "I want my column to be called . . ."
- System "What type of data will this column contain?"
- Human "The column will contain numbers"
- System "Where do you want this column to be placed?"
- . . .

So looking at a conversation like this, a text input and a simple drop-down field seem like the really *obvious* way to support this task, i.e. very intuitive.

I don't know who you tested or even what type of test you performed, but I struggle to understand why someone would find a text field and simple drop-down field confusing (i.e. the opposite to intuitive), when it is aligned so closely with the natural "conversation" a human has with a computer.

Comment: Appreciate all the comments, thank you. The problem in using only a text input and a drop down is the mis-fit with user's mental models. The problem is that without using a preview of a table, the only indication that these choices become a column is the title of this section - Define Cloumns. So I still think a WYSIWYG component of creating a table is better. I just didn't find any website that has done this before.

Comment: I just demonstrated that the flow between the user and the website is absolutely not confusing - in fact it is very clear. I need to see your design before commenting any further. Can you share a rough mock-up?

Comment: So a text field and a drop-down is not the confusing part, which suggests there is something else in your interaction design which is causing the usability problems you identified in your testing.